ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE upgrading Next.js 14 to 15 with npx @next/codemod@canary upgrade latest
I’m trying to upgrade my Next.js project from version 14 to 15 using the following command: npx @next/codemod@canary upgrade latest
The command starts successfully and asks which codemods I want to apply and if I want to upgrade to React 19. However, after that, I get the following error:
Error: Failed to install dependencies
    at runInstallation (/home/esteban/.npm/_npx/6a090669e21b4303/node_modules/@next/codemod/lib/handle-package.js:98:15)
    at runUpgrade (/home/esteban/.npm/_npx/6a090669e21b4303/node_modules/@next/codemod/bin/upgrade.js:260:42)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/home/esteban/.npm/_npx/6a090669e21b4303/node_modules/@next/codemod/bin/next-codemod.js:51:9) {
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: Command failed with ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE:  install
  The "file" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
      at normalizeSpawnArguments (node:child_process:548:3)
      at Object.spawnSync (node:child_process:836:8)
      at module.exports.sync (/home/esteban/.npm/_npx/6a090669e21b4303/node_modules/execa/index.js:169:25)
      at runInstallation (/home/esteban/.npm/_npx/6a090669e21b4303/node_modules/@next/codemod/lib/handle-package.js:91:25)
      at runUpgrade (/home/esteban/.npm/_npx/6a090669e21b4303/node_modules/@next/codemod/bin/upgrade.js:260:42)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async Command.<anonymous> (/home/esteban/.npm/_npx/6a090669e21b4303/node_modules/@next/codemod/bin/next-codemod.js:51:9) {
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE',
    originalMessage: 'The "file" argument must be of type string. Received undefined',
    shortMessage: 'Command failed with ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE:  install\n' +
      'The "file" argument must be of type string. Received undefined',
    command: ' install',
    exitCode: undefined,
    signal: undefined,
    signalDescription: undefined,
    stdout: '',
    stderr: '',
    all: '',
    failed: true,
    timedOut: false,
    isCanceled: false,
    killed: false
  }
}

I tried both accepting and refusing the React 19 update, but neither resolved the issue.
I’ve tried clearing the npm cache and reinstalling dependencies, but the issue persists.
However, updating Next.js manually and applying the individual codemods separately worked without any problems.
Has anyone faced this error before, or does anyone have ideas on how to debug this issue?
Node.js version: 20.17.0
npm version: 10.9.1
Next.js version before upgrade: 14.2.13
OS: Fedora OS
EDIT:
It needed a package-lock.json
